# React v4 and Redux: Update URL after API call to show new route?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my React application, I am trying to direct the user to "/" after a successful login. If possible, I need the page to **not** refresh after a successful login. Here is the code I have for when the API needs to be called (resp.data is sent when the user is authenticated):

```
handleFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    API.signin({
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password
    }).then(resp => {
      if (resp.data) {

      // console.log(resp);
      // window.location.replace(resp.data);
      window.history.pushState({}, null, resp.data);

    } else {
      console.log("Authentication was unsuccessful, or passport did not send back information.")
    }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Using `window.history.pushState({}, null, resp.data);` works for changing the URL. However, the components don't update (I have BrowserRouter routes specified for /login, /signup, and /). Additionally, `window.location.replace(resp.data);` refreshes the page. Is there a way to do this through react?

Comment: Render react-router's `<Redirect>` component conditionally.

Comment: @sn42 I apologize, I am still learning the basics of React. To conditionally render a <Redirect>, would I need to specify this where the other routes are specified?

Comment: ...also use react-router's `withRouter()` and [`props.history.push()`](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/) instead of `window.history`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) HoC provided by the `react-router` package to inject some properties into your components. You're interested in the history object from `react-router`, not the history object on window.

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'

class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  handleFormSubmit = event => {
    ...
    API.signin({
      ...
    }).then(resp => {
      if(resp.data) {
        const {history} = this.props
        history.push('/', {
          data
        })
      }
    })
  }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

Using withRouter will make `{match, location, history}` objects available in your component. With the above pattern your user will be redirected to your '/' route provided you have a `<Route path='/'/>` component in your `<Router/>` tree. The `data` will be available on `location.state.data`. (You'll need to wrap your home component with `withRouter` as well to have access to the `location` object.